# How to achieve nested alignment of formulas?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, context, nesting

I'm trying to get a nested alignment in math mode:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| ..... & ................                                       |
|       +--------------------------------------------------+     |
|       | ..... & .................                        |     |
|       |         .............................            |     |
|       +--------------------------------------------------+     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Using

```
\startformula
  \startalign
    \NC ..... \NC ................ \NR
    \NC       \NC \startalign
              \NC ..... \NC ................. \NR
              \NC       \NC .............................
              \stopalign
  \stopalign
\stopformula
```

does not produce the desired result.

How can I achieve this alignment?

Comment: ConTeXt does not have an equivalent of `amsmath`'s `aligned` environment; but the `matrix` environment should do what you want. Have a look at Section 9.3 of [Using \startalign](http://dl.contextgarden.net/myway/mathalign.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on Aditya's response I am now using

```
\starttext
\definemathmatrix
  [aligned]
  [n=2,distance=0pt,align={right,left},style=\displaystyle]

  \startformula
    \startalign
      \NC .... = \{ \NC ............. \NR
      \NC           \NC \startaligned
                          \NC |.........: \NC .................. \NR
                          \NC             \NC \land .........    \NR
                        \stopaligned \NR
      \NC \} \NC
    \stopalign
  \stopformula
\stoptext
```

which gives me precisely the layout I wanted.